# VBA value Error while copy pasting sheets from another workbook

Tags: excel, vba, copy-paste

I have the below VBA code which I am using, however, it is pasting external links as well. Some of which turn to Value errors. Is there a way I can modify it to paste only values and formats?

Sub GetSheets()

```
Path = "XXXX"
Filename = Dir(Path & "*.xlsx")
Do While Filename <> ""
Workbooks.Open Filename:=Path & Filename, ReadOnly:=True

For Each Workbook In Workbooks
    If Workbook.Name <> ThisWorkbook.Name Then
Workbook.Worksheets("SAC Input").Copy Before:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
ActiveSheet.Name = Workbook.Name

End If
Next
Set Workbook = Nothing
Workbooks(Filename).Close
Filename = Dir()
Loop
End Sub
```

Thank you.

Comment: `Workbook.Worksheets("SAC Input").UsedRange.Value = Workbook.Worksheets("SAC Input").UsedRange.Value` before copying, then don't save changes when closing.

Comment: There's no need for a `For Each` loop here. Use a workbook variable: `Dim wb As Workbook`, `Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=Path & Filename, ReadOnly:=True)`, then refer to `wb.Worksheets("SAC Input")`.

Comment: @bigben you've closed this as a duplicate of a Q that addresses different issues to those you've addressed in comments (although somewhat related).  Maybe you should reopen and answer this?

Comment: @chrisneilsen - I'm sure there's a better dupe target, will go looking. EDIT: found several.